# Cannot load image in ggez/rust due to path not absolute

Tags: image, rust, runtime-error, ggez

I get this strange error that ggez cannot find and load my image file. But even an absolute path still makes an error. Wtf man?

```
MyGame {
    carimage: Image::new(&mut ctx, "/home/arkadiusz/Dokumenty/competition-0008-gamedev/source/car_yellow_small_5.png").unwrap(),
}
```

Runtime error:

thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ResourceNotFound("/home/arkadiusz/Dokumenty/competition-0008-gamedev/source/car_yellow_small_5.png", [("/home/arkadiusz/Dokumenty/competition-0008-gamedev/source/target/release/resources", IOError(Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" })), ("/home/arkadiusz/.local/share/competition8:gamedev", IOError(Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" })), ("/home/arkadiusz/.config/competition8:gamedev", IOError(Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }))])', src/main.rs:26:93

The file is there:

```
$ ll /home/arkadiusz/Dokumenty/competition-0008-gamedev/source/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arkadiusz arkadiusz   993 lip  7  2015 car_yellow_small_5.png
```

Comment: The documentation of ggez explains what the path argument is: https://docs.rs/ggez/0.5.1/ggez/filesystem/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it solved itself. I dont know how I did it. Sorry.

```
MyGame {
    carimage: Image::new(&mut ctx, "/car_yellow_small_5.png").unwrap(),
}
```

Comment: But it's documented. And there's nowhere specified you can use absolute paths. I suggest you have a look at the documentation because ggez relies on conventions a lot.

Comment: The previous error told me the path must be absolute.

Comment: It was an internal error because ggez is quite young and lacks internal checks. Creating an issue might be a good idea.